# How can I make a loop faster?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, loops, line

I have an array of values that represent points on a line chart:

```
$temperatures = [23, 24, null, '', 25, '', '', null];
```

I'm using PHP4, but I think it can be answered in any language.

Array contains only numbers, nulls and empty strings.

Numbers represent temperatures, nulls mean that the instruments weren't working and empty strings represent neither (instruments are working, just not measuring anything).

Points must (in most cases) be connected, since it's a line chart.

I have a variable `$gap` that corresponds to each point and tells whether this point is connected to the next point. If it is set to `true`, than the points are not connected (`false` otherwise). For example, $gap for `temperatures[0]` must be set to `false`, since the line is drawn between `temperatures[0]` and temperatures[1]`(they are both valid temperatures). $gap for`temperatures[1]`and`temperatures[2]` must be true, since there is null following. And so on.

When there is null the $gap is absolutely `true`. For numbers and empty strings, it depends on: if a null follows, gap is true; if a number follows, gap is false. If empty string follows, we must check if afterwards comes null or number and apply the previous sentence accordingly. If there are just empty strings following, gap is true. Here is my code that is working too slow, but produce correct results:

```
$limit = count($temperatures);
for ($i = 0; $i <= limit; $i++) {
    $next_is_number = false;
    if (is_null($temperatures[i]) {
        $gap = true;
    } else {
        for ($y = $i + 1; $i <= limit; $i++) {
            if (is_null($temperatures[$y]) {
                break;
            } elsif (is_numeric($temperatures[$y]) {
                $next_is_number = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($next_is_number) {
           $gap = false;
        } else {
           $gap = true;
        }
    }      
}
```

How can I speed it up?

Comment: What do empty strings actually represent, though? The instrument was working but no data was gathered? Is it an error or simply missing information?

Comment: You seem to check from the current position (`$y = $i + 1`) to the end of the list each time.  Do you really just want to check that the next entry is blank/null rather than any entry is blank or null?

Comment: I don't think you need 2nd forLoop which is nested loop. Just remove that line having 2nd loop and its respective closing "}" and remove those two lines having "break;". and also replace $y with $i+1 and your program should work fine and maybe faster too

Comment: @Ashish The loop is needed, sadly.

Comment: @NigelRen What if the next one is blank or null?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 but in 2nd loop, loop will iterate 2nd time only when next temperature value is string and that condition that "if temperature is string" is already being handled in the last else part.

Comment: No, it's not. The loop is the thing handling that.

Comment: if value of gap can be decided by knowing current iterating temperature value and next temperature value, then 2nd loop is not needed but in case of next temperature value is empty string, do we have to go further and check temp[3rd index] and then 4th index until we find null or number to decide whether value of gap for current iterating temperature is true or false? I think question is little unclear here as Mandy has not written anything like this in his question but written the logic in his code.

Comment: @Ashish, we need a loop, since yes, it is not enough to simply know the next value. If the next value is an empty string, we need to go further, until we reach either a null or a number. In case it's a number, gap is false (line is connected). In case it's a null, gap is true (line is not connected).

Comment: @wizzwizz4, empty strings are as yu said - instrument was working, but it didn't need to gather any data.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your time and effort!

Comment: As we mentioned yesterday the best performance gain you would see if you upgraded to PHP 7. PHP 4 should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through backwards, remembering the last valid value and putting that in when you see an empty string. Then it's O(n) worst case, not O(n^2).

Alternatively, you can work from `$y - 1` to `$x` (or vice versa) after the inner loop, setting the values of your gaps array / outputting values, then skip past all the ones you've just done (`$x = $y`). This is also O(n).

Then, once you've got the algorithm as fast as you can, you can ditch PHP and write it in something like Rust or C. (I don't recall any true arrays in the language, so they're always going to be slow.)

Comment: thank you for your reply! It took me a while to understand what you mean, but now I think it's perfect. May I ask, if you don't mind, how you came to it? Is there a way (besides more practice) to learn about such algorithms? Thank you very much again!

Comment: @Mandy Mostly practice. Specifically, I noticed that you were working out several values only to throw them away, so I figured out a way that you could store them.

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks whether there is a a gap somewhere in your line chart or not.

So once a gap is found, there no reason to continue in the outer for-loop. Think of a chart of 1000 values, if there is a gap between the first two values it makes no sense to continue checking the other 998 values.

Thus, the first thing I would recommend is to set $gap = false at the beginning and to leave the loop once $gap is true. You could do that either with

1.) break (not so elegant),

2.) extract your code to a method and add a return-statement or

3.) adding a condition in the for-loop. I am not familiar with php but in most languages it is possible to do it like this:

```
     $gap = false;
     $limit = count($temperatures);
     for ($i = 0; $i <= limit && !$gap; $i++) {

     [...]
```

So once $gap is true, the outer for-loop is left.

Comment: i wish it was that simple! I should have written that $gap MUST get set for each point/element of an array. My code checks whether there is a gap between each two points.